# configure architecture?

Tags: macports, gcc

When trying to install a more recent version of subversion, I get an installation error for 'apr'. When I look at the log file, it says:

```
:debug:main Using compiler 'Mac OS X gcc 4.0'
:debug:configure Environment: CPATH='/opt/local/include' CFLAGS='-O2 -arch i386' CPPFLAGS='-I/opt/local/include' CXXFLAGS='-O2 -arch i386' LIBRARY_PATH='/opt/local/lib' MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='10.5' ac_cv_path_SED='sed' CXX='/usr/bin/g++-4.0' CC_PRINT_OPTIONS_FILE='/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_apr/work/.CC_PRINT_OPTIONS' F90FLAGS='-O2 -m32' LDFLAGS='-L/opt/local/lib -arch i386' FCFLAGS='-O2 -m32' lt_ECHO='/bin/echo' OBJC='/usr/bin/gcc-4.0' INSTALL='/usr/bin/install -c' FFLAGS='-O2 -m32' OBJCFLAGS='-O2 -arch i386' CC_PRINT_OPTIONS='YES' ac_cv_prog_AWK='awk' CC='/usr/bin/gcc-4.0'
```

and so on, but my gcc version is

```
i686-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.0.1 (GCC) 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)
```

Is this the issue? Does anyone know how I can get around this?

Comment: I've already done 'port -d selfupdate' and the apr error comes up also during the 'port -f upgrade outdated' operation (in addition to just straightforward subversion installation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple

```
sudo port clean apr
```

seemed to do the trick. I didn't have to move anything out of `/usr/local/` (which seems like a pretty aggressive demand!)
http://trac.macports.org/ticket/26809